# Is there a way to plot 2 or more acfs under single plot

Tags: r

I have a time series data frame. I have two continuous variables for which I need to plot the autocorrelation (acf) functions. I am trying to use `plot_grid()` to make sure that two plots are shown in a single window, but that is not happening. Here is the example:

```
#df is dataframe; col1 and col2 are continuous variables

p1 <- acf(df$col1,lag.max = 5 ,plot = TRUE) 
p2 <- acf(df$col2,lag.max = 5 ,plot = TRUE)
plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2,ncol =1,rel_heights = c(2/1,2/1),rel_widths = c(2/2,2/2))
```

```
    f <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1505779200, 1505779500, 1505779800, 
 1505780100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
     A = c(212.429693925327, 211.464088210329, 211.653306685973, 
     210.981936189015), B= c(75.9448191760481, 76.2501222022257, 
     76.1316674891558, 76.8299563088116)), row.names = c(NA, 4L
 ), class = "data.frame")
p1 <- acf(f$A, lag.max = 5, plot = FALSE) 
p2 <- acf(f$B, lag.max = 5, plot = FALSE)

cowplot::plot_grid(autoplot(p1), autoplot(p2), nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

`plot_grid` is from the `cowplot` package (I think) and works on grid-based graphics objects (i.e. output from `ggplot2`/`lattice`). `acf()` uses base graphics.  Something using `par(mfrow ...)` should work, like this:

```
orig_pars <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
acf(df$col1,lag.max = 5 ,plot = TRUE) 
acf(df$col2,lag.max = 5 ,plot = TRUE)
pars(orig_pars) ## reset
```

Or you can

- look around for a grid-based ACF plot solution: someone may have written `ggacf` or the equivalent
- extract the data from the `acf()` object and create your own plots with lattice/ggplot

Comment: A grid based version is offered in the ggfortify-package with autoplot(p1), etc.

Comment: @kath, you could post that as an answer if you wanted (or edit mine: I could make it "community wiki")

Answer (score 0):

A grid-based solution could be

```
library(ggfortify)

p1 <- acf(my_df$A, lag.max = 5, plot = FALSE)
p2 <- acf(my_df$B, lag.max = 5, plot = FALSE)

cowplot::plot_grid(autoplot(p1), autoplot(p2), nrow = 2)
```

[image]

If you want to add titles or labels to the plot you can do:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(autoplot(p1) + ggtitle("A"), autoplot(p2) + ggtitle("B"), nrow = 2)

# "AUTO" adds captial letters A, B, ... to the plots, but 
# you can also specify your own labels as a vector
cowplot::plot_grid(autoplot(p1), autoplot(p2), nrow = 2, labels = "AUTO")
```

**Data**

```
my_df <-
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(1505779200, 1505779500, 1505779800, 1505780100),
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),
                 A = c(212.429693925327, 211.464088210329, 211.653306685973, 210.981936189015),
                 B = c(75.9448191760481, 76.2501222022257, 76.1316674891558, 76.8299563088116)),
            row.names = c(NA, 4L),
            class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. I get this error ````Error in .Call.graphics(C_palette2, .Call(C_palette2, NULL)) : 
  invalid graphics state````

Comment: @DevP Can you provide a reproducible example of your data? I tried with some dummy data and it worked out fine for me.

Comment: It works for me - please try again in a fresh R session.

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way add the title here for respective columns? Like first plot is for Column A and second is for Column B

Comment: @DevP see my edit. Please consider also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using base R, then the following code can be used

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
for(i in 2:ncol(f)) {
  y <- f[,i]
  name <- names(f)[i]
  plot(acf(y,plot=F, na.action = na.pass)[1:5],main=name)
}
```

[image]